# Should I dual-boot Ubuntu and windows or use a VM?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, virtual-machine

I am interested in dual booting Ubuntu on my windows 11 machine. I would use Ubuntu for programming and general use. Which should i use?

Comment: Before doing that look at WSL which brings Ubuntu to windows.

Comment: As stated by @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why not just use [WSL2](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support) and install ubuntu as an app in your Windows? You can even install a graphical interface iirc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure linux experience with full CPU and memory with little bit of disk complication ( when you dual boot you need to create new partition ) then you should dual boot and if you are going to use your linux for general use then you should use VM or WSL as it gets things done without any complicated stuff.

Comment: Does WSL do the same thing a VM?

Comment: Yes almost, WSL2 is almost like VM you won't notice any difference in day to day usage. However I noticed some limitation in advaced usage in wsl.

Comment: Thanks! In all tutorials and videos about WSL, all i can see is that it is a linux kernal. Is it actually interactive like a VM and i can go to the desktop and search the web?

Comment: Yes, you can install your favourite desktop environment and use the linux desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not a big fan of dual booting. If you only have one drive where you'd need to set up multiple partitions to boot from, that makes it more of a headache. I've heard of situations where Windows overwrites Grub configurations when on the same drive.

If you want to use Ubuntu for programming, I would recommend WSL for this. You'll primarily rely on the Linux command line and Windows GUI apps for your workflow.

If you want more of the *total* Linux experience with a different desktop environment and such, I'd recommend beginning with a VM. If you find that you like that workflow and want the native experience, then maybe look to dual boot.

My guess would be that for your use case, WSL would be the best option to integrate with your existing Windows 11 setup.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you going for the dual-boot, for several reasons:

- you will learn a lot about the partitioning, boot loaders (such as GRUB), `swap`, the `suspend` function of the OS, etc.;
- if you are low on resources on your computer (low on RAM, and low CPU power), then, as @vaibhav1313 mentioned, dual boot is better, because you are getting full memory and CPU power on each system you boot into;
- from time to time a friend comes to me and says that his/her virtual machine with Windows (on the host Linux/Ubuntu) is broken -- I had similar experiences with virtual machines on the desktop -- a lot of things can happen. Sometimes you will not be able to recover. The worst thing that can "just" happen to you with dual-boot (even if you are careful) are boot loader problems -- noting you cannot get fixed yourself, learning your bit about boot loaders in the process;
- it depends on what you are planning to do, but you can experience network issues on the VM Windows when trying to connect to external devices, networks, VPNs, etc. (No such problems when dual-booting.) Even sharing files between the host system and a VM is not available out-of-the-box, and you have to configure it (although it is sometimes just checking a checkbox -- you have to know about this). While with dual boot, there is no problem with file transfer between the partitions, at least when you are accessing Windows files from the Ubuntu system (the other way around can get tricky).

Btw., I agree with @zzzachzzz that you need several partitions for dual-booting, but even with a 256GB drive it is still reasonable to have 2 systems in dual-boot (even with VM you need like 80GB or so on the Windows system), and creating partitions during Windows or Ubuntu installation process has never been easier. There is nothing wrong with what @zzzachzzz suggested, i.e., starting with a VM, I did so myself, but very quickly I switched to dual-boot, and I am still using it today, years later.

Comment: Wsl2 can use all the memory you machine has, and does it unless told otherwise